# Fade out/in two divs at different times on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

Basically I'm looking to replicate a similar effect to this site: http://www.falve.co.nz/collection/ When you scroll down the nav fades out pretty quickly, then as you continue to scroll the hero text gently fades out according to the scroll position. When you scroll back up to the top they all fade back in again, with the hero text first then the nav.

I'm trying to replicate this but my code below simply will not work:

```
// Global vars
  var $artHeaderInner = $('#scene');
  var $nav = $('#prim');
  var windowScroll;

    // Functional parallaxing calculations
    function slidingTitle() {

        //Get scroll position of window
        windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        //Slow scroll of .art-header-inner scroll and fade it out

        $artHeaderInner.css({
            'margin-top' : -(windowScroll/3)+"px",
            'opacity' : 1-(windowScroll/550)
        });

        //Fade the .nav out
        $nav.css({
            'opacity' : 1-(windowScroll/400)
        });
    }
```

Comment: have you attached the function to the window scroll event?

Comment: Is there more to the code than what you've got here? Because all you have, so far, is a function and some css-modification jQuery inside that function, but I don't see anything hooking up to any scroll events.

Comment: Ah I see, i've now done this and all works. Thanks for the tip.